# Overriding a makefile variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a master makefile which has the default values for variables and then a child makefile which includes project specific settings. At the end of the child makefile, I include the master makefile.

I have been using the following code in the master makefile to set default values for a variable

```
ifndef CC
    CC = avr-gcc
endif
```

And then recently I read that I can also do

```
CC ?= avr-gcc
```

So my question is, whether both are same and if yes which one is the recommended way of overriding variables.

Comment: Forgetting about the `?=` for the moment: I'm not sure I see the point of wrapping the CC assignment with `ifndef CC`.  The GNU make manual makes it clear that command-line variable assignments take precedence over assignments in the makefile, unless you use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is broadly understood, easier to read and causes less clutter.

The first way, using `ifndef / endif` is more for instances where you want to do *more* than just set a variable, like toggling many things depending on if `DEBUG` is set, or something else.

If you just want to set a variable *if* it's not already set, then `var ?= value` is definitely sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I need to wait for another 4 minutes to accept your answer though :)

Comment: It turns out that both `CC` and `CXX` can't be overridden http://stackoverflow.com/q/18887053/24949

Comment: @Sudar I suspect something else is setting them after you set / export them in your makefile - any kids assigning outright instead of conditionally? `=` instead of `?=` ?