# Overriding `CC` and `CXX` variables in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a master makefile, which contains generic settings, and a child makefile that has project specific settings.

From my other question about [overriding variables in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18869628/24949), I learned that I can use the following code in my master makefile:

```
CC ?= avr-gcc
CXX ?= avr-g++
```

In the child makefile, I use [colorgcc](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc) and override these variables:

```
CC ?= color-avr-gcc
CXX ?= color-avr-g++
```

Everything works.

But, if I remove the above lines from my child makefile, make starts using `gcc` and `g++` instead of `avr-gcc` and `avr-g++`.

I guess both `CC` and `CXX` are treated differently and they are provided with default values by make and I am not able to assign default values to them using the following statements:

```
CC ?= avr-gcc
CXX ?= avr-g++
```

My questions:

- Is my assumption correct?
- If yes, is there any other way to provide default values to `CC` and `CXX` in the master makefile and let make use it, if I don't override them in the child makefile?

**Edit**:

As per [Chrono Kitsune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539810/chrono-kitsune)'s suggestion I did the following

**master makefile**

```
CC = avr-gcc
CXX = avr-g++
# Add other master macros here.
# Add other master targets here.
```

**child makefile**

```
CC ?= color-avr-gcc
CXX ?= color-avr-g++
# There are no child macros or targets

include master.mk
```

Unfortunately, even this didn't work. When I run `make child.mk` it is picking up the `CC` and `CXX` defined in master.

PS: BTW, my master makefile is a makefile for Arduino and the full source code is available in [github](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/arduino-mk/Arduino.mk).

Comment: `?=` sets the variable IFF it is not already set.  So, this actually does the _opposite_ of "overriding" a variable; it explicitly does NOT override a variable value if it's already set.  If you want to override you should use just `=`, not `?=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging it using the [origin](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) function, I finally made to work with the following combination.

**Master makefile**

```
CC = avr-gcc
CXX = avr-g++
# Add other master macros here.
# Add other master targets here.
```

**Child makefile**

```
include master.mk

CC = color-avr-gcc
CXX = color-avr-g++
# There are no child macros or targets
```

Now when I do `make child.mk` it picks up `color-avr-gcc`. And if I comment it in child makefile, then it uses `avr-gcc` from master makefile.

Answer (score 3):

Split your master makefile into two files: master.macros and master.targets. The .macros file will contain any macros such as CC and CXX, and the .targets file will contain the actual targets to make.

Child makefile:

```
CC ?= color-avr-gcc
CXX ?= color-avr-g++
# Add other child macros here.

include master.macros

# Add child targets here.

include master.targets
```

master.macros:

```
CC = avr-gcc
CXX = avr-g++
# Add other master macros here.
```

master.targets:

```
# Add master targets here.
```

If you set CC on the command line, the entire project will use that. Otherwise if CC is set in the child makefile, the entire project will use that CC. If neither is used, the entire project will use the CC macro in master.macros.

If you need anything more complicated, such as a different CC being used in building master targets only, you will want to use a different CC variable such as MASTER_CC that defaults to $(CC), though you can override it as needed by using a command line like `make MASTER_CC=avr-gcc` if you don't want to use whatever CC is in the child makefile. You'd use the ?= assignment, and all rules would need to be explicit and you would substitute any $(CC) in a rule for $(MASTER_CC) of course:

master.macros:

```
MASTER_CC ?= $(CC)
MASTER_CXX ?= $(CXX)
```

It will use color-avr-gcc for example if that is the value of CC. Otherwise, you'd need to use `make MASTER_CC=avr-gcc` to use avr-gcc instead. I haven't tested this last bit, meaning there are probably bugs, but I'd imagine the first solution is what you need: split the master makefile into two files, and use `CC ?= ...` in the part containing only master macros and the child makefile.

Comment: I just tried it, but even this didn't work. I have updated the question with what I tried and the new code. Anyway thanks for your help.